# how to make arrow that loops in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

what is the right way to draw an arrow that loops back to point to its origin in matplotlib? i tried:

```
plt.figure()
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.annotate("", xy=(0.6, 0.9),
             xycoords="figure fraction",
             xytext = (0.6, 0.8),
             textcoords="figure fraction",
             fontsize = 10, \
             color = "k",
             arrowprops=dict(edgecolor='black',
                             connectionstyle="angle,angleA=-180,angleB=45",
                             arrowstyle = '<|-',
                             facecolor="k",
                             linewidth=1,
                             shrinkA = 0,
                             shrinkB = 0))
plt.show()
```

this doesn't give the right result:

[image: arrow]

the `connectionstyle` arguments are hard to follow from this page (http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html).

i'm looking for is something like [this](http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/25282609/6/stock-illustration-25282609-arrow-sign-refresh-reload-loop-rotation-pictogram-black-icon.jpg) or [this](https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-volume-5/48/280-512.png):

[image: loopy arrow]

**update:** the answer linked to does not show how do this with `plt.annotate` which has other features i want to use. the proposal to use `$\circlearrowleft$` marker is not a real solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the easiest way to create an easily modifiable looping arrow is to use [patches](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html). I've pasted code to do this below. Change the variables in the variables section and things should all rotate and scale together. You can play around with the patch that creates the arrow head to make a different shape though I suspect that this triangle will be the easiest one.

```
%matplotlib inline
# from __future__ import division #Uncomment for python2.7
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc, RegularPolygon
import numpy as np
from numpy import radians as rad

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
ax = plt.gca()
def drawCirc(ax,radius,centX,centY,angle_,theta2_,color_='black'):
    #========Line
    arc = Arc([centX,centY],radius,radius,angle=angle_,
          theta1=0,theta2=theta2_,capstyle='round',linestyle='-',lw=10,color=color_)
    ax.add_patch(arc)


    #========Create the arrow head
    endX=centX+(radius/2)*np.cos(rad(theta2_+angle_)) #Do trig to determine end position
    endY=centY+(radius/2)*np.sin(rad(theta2_+angle_))

    ax.add_patch(                    #Create triangle as arrow head
        RegularPolygon(
            (endX, endY),            # (x,y)
            3,                       # number of vertices
            radius/9,                # radius
            rad(angle_+theta2_),     # orientation
            color=color_
        )
    )
    ax.set_xlim([centX-radius,centY+radius]) and ax.set_ylim([centY-radius,centY+radius]) 
    # Make sure you keep the axes scaled or else arrow will distort

drawCirc(ax,1,1,1,0,250)
drawCirc(ax,2,1,1,90,330,color_='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I find no way to make a loop using `plt.annotate` only once, but using it four times works :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

# coordinates of the center of the loop
x_center = 0.5 
y_center = 0.5 

radius = 0.2
# linewidth of the arrow
linewidth = 1

ax.annotate("", (x_center + radius, y_center), (x_center, y_center + radius),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",
                            shrinkA=10,  # creates a gap between the start point and end point of the arrow
                            shrinkB=0,
                            linewidth=linewidth,
                            connectionstyle="angle,angleB=-90,angleA=180,rad=10"))    

ax.annotate("", (x_center, y_center - radius), (x_center + radius, y_center), 
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",
                            shrinkA=0, 
                            shrinkB=0,
                            linewidth=linewidth,
                            connectionstyle="angle,angleB=180,angleA=-90,rad=10"))    

ax.annotate("", (x_center - radius, y_center),  (x_center, y_center - radius), 
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",
                            shrinkA=0, 
                            shrinkB=0,
                            linewidth=linewidth,
                            connectionstyle="angle,angleB=-90,angleA=180,rad=10"))    
ax.annotate("", (x_center, y_center + radius), (x_center - radius, y_center), 
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>",
                            facecolor="k",
                            linewidth=linewidth,
                            shrinkA=0, 
                            shrinkB=0,
                            connectionstyle="angle,angleB=180,angleA=-90,rad=10"))


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xlim(1,3) 
ax.set_ylim(1,3)
ax.plot([2.5],[2.5],marker=r'$\circlearrowleft$',ms=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: i'd like to use the arrow styles in ``plt.annotate``, not this arrow. also this gives no flexibility about the angle or the arrow head size, etc. your solution also relies on tex and on tex's fonts.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion uses just the plot command

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def circarrowdraw(x0, y0, radius=1, aspect=1, direction=270, closingangle=-330,
                  arrowheadrelativesize=0.3, arrowheadopenangle=30, *args):
    """
    Circular arrow drawing. x0 and y0 are the anchor points.
    direction gives the angle of the circle center relative to the anchor
    in degrees. closingangle indicates how much of the circle is drawn
    in degrees with positive being counterclockwise and negative being
    clockwise. aspect is important to make the aspect of the arrow 
    fit the current figure.
    """

    xc = x0 + radius * np.cos(direction * np.pi / 180)
    yc = y0 + aspect * radius * np.sin(direction * np.pi / 180)

    headcorrectionangle = 5

    if closingangle < 0:
        step = -1
    else:
        step = 1
    x = [xc + radius * np.cos((ang + 180 + direction) * np.pi / 180)
         for ang in np.arange(0, closingangle, step)]
    y = [yc + aspect * radius * np.sin((ang + 180 + direction) * np.pi / 180)
         for ang in np.arange(0, closingangle, step)]

    plt.plot(x, y, *args)

    xlast = x[-1]
    ylast = y[-1]

    l = radius * arrowheadrelativesize

    headangle = (direction + closingangle + (90 - headcorrectionangle) *
                 np.sign(closingangle))

    x = [xlast +
         l * np.cos((headangle + arrowheadopenangle) * np.pi / 180),
         xlast,
         xlast +
         l * np.cos((headangle - arrowheadopenangle) * np.pi / 180)]
    y = [ylast +
         aspect * l * np.sin((headangle + arrowheadopenangle) * np.pi / 180),
         ylast,
         ylast +
         aspect * l * np.sin((headangle - arrowheadopenangle) * np.pi / 180)]

    plt.plot(x, y, *args)
```

To test it:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(10)**2, 'b.')
bb = plt.gca().axis()
asp = (bb[3] - bb[2]) / (bb[1] - bb[0])
circarrowdraw(6, 36 , radius=0.4, aspect=asp, direction=90)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use tikz to generate the figure:

```
    \documentclass {minimal}
    \usepackage {tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \usetikzlibrary {arrows}
    \begin {tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
    \draw[-angle 90, line width=5.0mm, rounded corners=20pt] 
    (0.25,0)--   (1.0, 0.0) -- (1.0, -3.0) -- (-3.0, -3.0) -- (-3.0, 0) --(-1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

there is a pgf/tikz backend in matplotlib that you could generate your matplotlib output to tikz code that pdflatex or lualatex can process.
So this way, I think, you could insert seamlessly the looparrow figure in
your matplotlib figure.
See for ex:
http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#pgf-tikz-backend

Answer (score 0):

@Aguy's answer is useful if you want a smooth arc instead of a complete circle. In Aguy's answer an arrow head is drawn line by line, but instead a FancyArrowPatch can be used. This gives a full arrow head, which might be more suitable. Below gives the code with the FancyArrowPatch arrow head.

```
def circarrowdraw(x0, y0, radius=1, aspect=1, direction=270, closingangle=-330, rotate_head = 0.0, color='b', *args):
    """
    Circular arrow drawing. x0 and y0 are the anchor points.
    direction gives the angle of the circle center relative to the anchor
    in degrees. closingangle indicates how much of the circle is drawn
    in degrees with positive being counterclockwise and negative being
    clockwise. aspect is important to make the aspect of the arrow 
    fit the current figure. rotate_head is used to rotate the arrow head
    by increasing the y value of the arrow's tail coordinate.
    """

    # Center of circle
    xc = x0 + radius * np.cos(direction * np.pi / 180)
    yc = y0 + aspect * radius * np.sin(direction * np.pi / 180)

    # Draw circle
    if closingangle < 0:
        step = -1
    else:
        step = 1
    x = [xc + radius * np.cos((ang + 180 + direction) * np.pi / 180)
         for ang in np.arange(0, closingangle, step)]
    y = [yc + aspect * radius * np.sin((ang + 180 + direction) * np.pi / 180)
         for ang in np.arange(0, closingangle, step)]
    plt.plot(x, y, *args, color=color)

    # Draw arrow head
    arc_arrow_head = patches.FancyArrowPatch((x[-1], y[-1] + rotate_head),
                                             (x[0], y[0]),
                                             arrowstyle="Simple,head_width=10,head_length=10,tail_width=0.01", 
                                             color = color,
                                             zorder = 10)
    plt.gca().add_patch(arc_arrow_head)
```

To test it:

```
plt.plot([0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
circarrowdraw(1.0, 1.0 , radius=0.1, aspect=0.3, direction=90, closingangle=-345, rotate_head = 0.003)
circarrowdraw(0.0, 1.0 , radius=0.1, aspect=1, direction=-90, closingangle=-345, rotate_head = 0.0)
circarrowdraw(0.0, 0.0 , radius=0.1, aspect=3.0, direction=90, closingangle=-345, rotate_head = 0.01)
circarrowdraw(1.0, 0.0 , radius=0.1, aspect=0.3, direction=-90, closingangle=-345)
plt.show()
```

[Picture of image (I don't have a high enough reputation to embed the image in my answer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXEvy.png)