# Complicated arrow shape in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a complicated arrow shape to a matplotlib to indicate a "jump." (See sketch)

[image: Rough sketch of what I want the plot to look like]

The code for generating the "wells" is simple enough, and here it is for reference.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.9)
L=2
def well(x,depth=10,centre=0,flatten=0.2):
    return -depth * np.exp(-0.5 * ((x-centre)/flatten)**2)

wells=[-2*L,-1*L,0,L,2*L]
wells_xs=[]
for centre in wells:
    wells_xs.append(np.linspace(centre-0.5*L,centre+0.5*L,100))

for center,space in zip(wells,wells_xs):
    d=8 if center==0 else 1
    flatten=0.3 if center==0 else 0.4
    ax.plot(space,well(space,d,center,flatten),'deepskyblue')
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to indicate the idea of something jumping from the right "dip" into the deep well, over the small "hill." So an arrow pointing directly from A to B won't look right.
(In the case of the plot, it's from wells[3] to wells[2], w.r.t. the x-axis)

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38208040/2280890) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

You can use `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch` to draw an arrow onto the figure.

## Answer

The `FancyArrowPatch` class from `matplotlib.patches` allows you to create a custom arrow to be added to a figure using `ax.add_patch(arrow)`. It can be a little fiddly choosing the right options to get the exact arrow shape that you want but this code should provide a good starting place. You can adjust the start/end points, the curvature, or even the connection style itself to change the path that the arrow takes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch


def well(x, depth=10, centre=0, flatten=0.2):
    return -depth * np.exp(-0.5 * ((x-centre)/flatten)**2)


def get_arrow(start_point, end_point, line_width=2.0, color="red", curvature=1.0, mutation_scale=20):
    arrow_style = f'->'
    connection_style = f'arc3, rad={curvature}'
    arrow = FancyArrowPatch(start_point, end_point, connectionstyle=connection_style, arrowstyle=arrow_style, color=color, linewidth=line_width, mutation_scale=mutation_scale)
    return arrow


fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.9)
L = 2

wells = [-2*L, -1*L, 0, L, 2*L]
wells_xs = []
for centre in wells:
    wells_xs.append(np.linspace(centre-0.5*L, centre+0.5*L, 100))

for center, space in zip(wells, wells_xs):
    d = 8 if center == 0 else 1
    flatten = 0.3 if center == 0 else 0.4
    ax.plot(space, well(space, d, center, flatten), 'deepskyblue')

start_point = (wells[3], 0)
end_point = (wells[2], -2)
arrow = get_arrow(start_point, end_point)

ax.add_patch(arrow)
plt.show()
```

[image: A figure with a curved red arrow drawn on.]

Comment: Ah, thanks a tonne! Exactly what I needed. I did search up documentation for matplotlib arrows, but the page on [fancyarrow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow.html) did not reveal a whole lot to me.